# looping through JSONObject and printing the result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop through a jsonobject and print the attribute name.Im using the below code to workon but not sure what is the problem.

js

```
var jsonobject = [{'name':'Bob','age':'20','sex':'male'},
                 {'name':'Tom','age':'30','sex':'male'},
                 {'name':'Mike','age':'40','sex':'male'},
                 ]

jsonobject.forEach(function(entry) {
    empname = entry.name;
    $('#test').html('<b>entry.name</b>')
})
```

html

```
<div id='test'>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use `var empname` for local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very near,
try this:

```
jsonobject.forEach(function(entry) {
    var empname = entry.name;
    $('#test').append('<b>'+empname+'</b><br />')
})
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VpDjR/1/)

What I changed:

- I concatenated the value `empname` with the concatenate operator `+`.
- used [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append) instead of [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html), otherwise you are always replacing in each new value.
- added a `<br />` just to make them show up in a new line.
- added `var` before `empname` to avoid interfearence in the global scope.

Comment: you were fast as well, +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append) and string concatenation to make use of the variable value. When you use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) it overwrites the previous value so at the end of the loop you will get only the last executions result

```
$('#test').append('<b>' + entry.name + '</b>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E65k4/)

Comment: you were fast, +1 for that :-)